# API to remotely upload secret to Thycotic Secret Server

Tags: rest, powershell

I am total newbie to PowerShell, Thycotic Secret Server and writing APIs. I have been tasked with writing an API to remotely access Thycotic Secret Server and upload a secret together with attached files. Unfortunately, I haven’t gotten off the starting block. I am following the code here:

https://thycotic.force.com/support/s/article/REST-API-PowerShell-Scripts-Getting-Started

I have copied down:
3 – Searching Secrets
4 – Create Secret and

Get-Token from here:
https://thycotic.force.com/support/s/article/Secret-Server-Trial-Using-the-API

and have created functions for each one. The only changes I made are to change myurl, myusername and mypassword.

This is my PowerShell script:

```
$myUrl = "mysecretserver/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f"
$application = "https://mysecretserver/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fsecretserver"

# Ask for user name
$userName = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter user name"
$userPassword = Read-Host -AsSecureString "Password"

[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}

Get-Token
Search-Secrets $userName,$userPassword
Create-Secret $userName,$userPassword
```

When I run Get-Token (no changes made to downloaded code)

```
function Get-Token
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Switch] $UseTwoFactor
    )

    $creds = @{
        username = $userName
        password = $userPassword
        grant_type = "password"
    };

    $headers = $null
    If ($UseTwoFactor) {
        $headers = @{
            "OTP" = (Read-Host -Prompt "Enter your OTP for 2FA (displayed in your 2FA app): ")
        }
    }

    try
    {
        $response = Invoke-RestMethod "$application/oauth2/token" -Method Post -Body $creds -Headers $headers;
        $token = $response.access_token;
        return $token;
    }
    catch
    {
        $result = $_.Exception.Response.GetResponseStream();
        $reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($result);
        $reader.BaseStream.Position = 0;
        $reader.DiscardBufferedData();
        $responseBody = $reader.ReadToEnd() | ConvertFrom-Json
        Write-Host "ERROR: $($responseBody.error)"
        return;
    }
}
```

It seems to run ok but when I display $token, it is empty. 
I'm not 100% sure what this is doing and have looked at a lot of examples but seem to be missing the basic steps for reading the token and using it to access the secret server. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your Secret Server URL with the Server's FQDN, not the web URL you get in a browser. You need to make sure the Secret Server address is correct otherwise it won't be hitting the API (and maybe failing gracefully which is why you don't see any errors from the `Get-Token` function).

For example, instead of:

```
$application = "https://mysecretserver/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fsecretserver"
```

It may be something like:

```
$application = "https://mysecretserver.mydomain.com"
```